# the $watch - method isnt changing the scope-variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have a `$scope.var=[]`
when i click a button, this array gets filled with content.
so the `$scope.var.length` is changing from 0 to 1 for example.

When the array gets filled I want to show a div, so it has a

```
ng-if="condition".
```

This condition is saved in the controller as well:

```
$scope.controller = false.
```

Now I want that condition to be changed, when the array get filled:

```
$scope.$watch('var.length', function(){$scope.condition = true;});
```

Now (important!), there is a second option to show the div: a button with

```
ng-click="condition = !condition"
```

In the test, the ng-click is working perfectly, and the condition is changing between true and false, but when i fill the var  = [] with content, the $watch-method isn´t working.
Thanks for help and tipps :)

**//EDIT**
html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div ng-click="condition= !condition">
                <span class="glyphicon clickable" ng-class="{'glyphicon-down': !condition, 'glyphicon-up': condition}" ></span>
            </div>
            <div class="slideToggle" ng-if="condition">
            Text hier
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Now... `ng-if` creates a separate scope... and that inline click is going to take the current scope level - so you probably have a `condition` variable defined at two different scope levels. Post your HTML.

Comment: How are you "filling" the array? That might be your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it:

change the `ng-click="condition = !condition"`
to `ng-click="reverse()"`

and in the controller you define the function:

```
 $scope.reverse= function(){
                    $scope.condition= !$scope.condition;
                };
```

Then the condition is changing as well, because it´s in the same scope now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just watch var itself instead of var.length

Check this out for an example :  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/577/

The code  -

```
   $scope.$watch('var', function(newVal, oldVal){
            console.log(newVal);
            if(newVal.length > 0 ){
                $scope.condition = true;
            }else{
                 $scope.condition = false;  
            }
        });
```

This should do the trick for you.

Alternatively, you can watch var.length but you still need some if/else logic inside to check if the newVal is actually 0 or not. Something like this  :

```
  $scope.$watch('var.length', function(newVal, oldVal){
            if(newVal === 0){
             $scope.condition = false;  
            } else { 
             $scope.condition = true;   
            }
        });
```

Comment: that´s working, when I remove the ng-click="condition = !condition". So the problem has to be there

Comment: @samron can you please post your html too

Comment: Okay, I did, I think it´s about different scopes

Comment: @samron a really quick test to check that would be change the ng-if to ng-show

Comment: I tested it: The watch-function is working: the newVal is changing! But The condition isnt

Comment: @samron looks like you got it by just moving the click logic into the controller :)

Answer (score 0):

Such a code may lead to several problems.
You can inspect my code:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LzBNCnI3dRV6M5pftfq?p=preview)
`$scope.$watch('var.length', function(newE) {
        if (newE > 0) {
            $scope.condition = true;
        }
    });`

1. The way your var changing your array, if they are equal you have to reinitialize it. Not a very smart idea but in other way you must ensure that you array filling creates new array and angular could see that.
2. to give it a possibility to change a scope you have to use `$timeout` in my case, so be care to not get trapped in `$apply` loop.